# c# Unable to resize html content within webview

Tags: c#, css, webview

I have a problem with resizing the contents of webview with the size that I have come up with. Currently, I have the following codes in the program. I am using awesomium :

```
public ClassroomGameWin ()
{
    if ((!WebCore.IsRunning) && (!initialized1))
    {
        WebCore.Initialize(WebConfig.Default);
       initialized1 = true;
    }

    InitializeComponent();
    wSession = WebCore.CreateWebSession(new WebPreferences() { CustomCSS = "body { transform: scale(1.6,1.6);}" });
    WebView newwindow = WebCore.CreateWebView(100, 100, wSession);

    InitializeView(newwindow);

    newwindow.Resize(300, 300);

    this.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(ClassroomGameWin_FormClosing);
    this.Load += new EventHandler(ClassroomGameWin_Load);            
    lock (lockObj)
    {
        forms.Add(this);
    }
}
```

:
:
:

```
internal ClassroomGameWin(WebView newwindow)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    InitializeView( newwindow );

    // We should immediately call a resize,
    // after wrapping child views.
    if (newwindow != null )
        newwindow.Resize( 300, 300 );
}
```

This is the problem that i am facing :
Content does not stretch to webform size

[image]

Focusing on the resizing instead of the HTML source codes is there a way to fix the issue?